# tinyMCE Image Upload to Directory Fails when $_POST['imageDIR'] used in postAcceptor.php

Tags: php, arrays, tinymce

Somewhat new to tinyMCE and javascript.  Would like to understand why the php image upload program supplied by the tinyMCE site does not work when I try to use the php $_POST[] superglobal to reference a directory name.

The `$_POST['imageDIR']` is the directory to store the images when added to the tinyMCE text area.  It works when I use `$imageFolder = "images3/";` - images get stored in that directory.  When I use `$imageFolder = $_POST['imagesDIR'];` ,where the $_POST value is set in another file (such as 'images45/'), the directory is NOT created, and the image is stored in the textarea as a base64 image string.

Trying to echo anything in the postAcceptor.php script to troubleshoot, also causes the same failure.

The tinyMCE config file is shown below (right from the tinyMCE website example):

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#article',
  plugins: 'image code,autoresize',
  menubar:false,
  statusbar: false,
  toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
  // enable title field in the Image dialog
  image_title: true, 
  // enable automatic uploads of images represented by blob or data URIs
  automatic_uploads: true,
  // URL of our upload handler (for more details check: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#images_upload_url)
  images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
  // here we add custom filepicker only to Image dialog
  file_picker_types: 'image', 
  // and here's our custom image picker
  image_advtab: true,
  file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

    // Note: In modern browsers input[type="file"] is functional without 
    // even adding it to the DOM, but that might not be the case in some older
    // or quirky browsers like IE, so you might want to add it to the DOM
    // just in case, and visually hide it. And do not forget do remove it
    // once you do not need it anymore.

    input.onchange = function() {
      var file = this.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function () {
        // Note: Now we need to register the blob in TinyMCEs image blob
        // registry. In the next release this part hopefully won't be
        // necessary, as we are looking to handle it internally.
        var id = 'imageID' + (new Date()).getTime();
        var blobCache =  tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
        var base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
        var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
        blobCache.add(blobInfo);

        // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
        cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

    input.click();
  }

});
```

The postAcceptor.php file is shown below (also from the tinyMCE website example):

```
<?php
  /*******************************************************
   * Only these origins will be allowed to upload images *
   ******************************************************/
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.1", "http://example.com");

  /*********************************************
   * Change this line to set the upload folder *
   *********************************************/
  $imageFolder = "images3/"; //----WORKS!!!
  $imageFolder = $_POST['imagesDIR']; //--NO WORK!!! 
  /*********************************************/  

  if (!file_exists($imageFolder)) {
    mkdir($imageFolder, 0777, true);
}
  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
      if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
      } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
        return;
      }
    }

    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

Any help to explain why the `$_POST` variable causes this failure would be appreciated.  Any suggestion as to how this could be done would help - my end goal is to be able to save the images in a directory named after the article ID, stored in a database.  The article ID changes depending on which article is called up from the database.  I have also tried to use the `$_SESSION['imagesDIR']` variable, which also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Using $_SESSION['imageDIR'] worked...just forgot to use session_start() at the top of the file!

$_POST I thought could be used as a global array variable, but seems like you need to pass this to other pages using the FORM/ACTION method and is not available beyond the originating script.